# mi home bluetooth thermometer 2 how to connect

Tags: bluetooth

I bought this device hoping to use it with my hobby project, a programmable home thermostat based on a Raspberry Pi board.

Using Python and the BLEAK library, I can find it on a BLE scan quite easily:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

def detection_callback(device, advertisement_data):
    print(device.address, "RSSI:", device.rssi, advertisement_data)
    
async def main():
    scanner = BleakScanner()
    scanner.register_detection_callback(detection_callback)
    await scanner.start()
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0)
    await scanner.stop()
    
    for d in scanner.discovered_devices:
        print(d)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

resulting in this, including RSSI of -72, which seems a reasonable value:

```
A4:C1:38:0F:C4:95 RSSI: -72 AdvertisementData(local_name='LYWSD03MMC', service_data={'0000fe95-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': b'0X[\x05\xa8\x95\xc4\x0f8\xc1\xa4\x08'})
```

But any attempt to follow this up by connecting to the device at this MAC address, times out. I would appreciate suggestions on how to correctly connect to this device to read the temperature.

Comment: This guy has got the goods. His example programs JUST WORK! The second one, List Services and Characteristics, connected flawlessly. https://nabeelvalley.co.za/docs/iot/bluetooth-intro/